# How to prevent TFS local files from being deleted / overwritten / renamed?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm using MS Team Foundation Server 2012 with a server workspace, and the local files are on a Linux server (accessed via Samba).  Accessing TFS from Visual Studio 2017.

When I check in foo.txt, TFS successfully sets foo.txt to read only as expected (r-xr--r--).  But TFS does NOT set the permissions for the directory in which foo.txt is stored.  Thus although I can't modify foo.txt, I still have write permissions to the directory it's in, so I can delete foo.txt or rename it or over-write it.

Is there a way I can tell TFS to manage the permissions of the directory a file is stored in (in addition to the file itself)?  So that I would NOT be able to delete/rename/overwrite a file (outside of Visual Studio) without first checking it out of TFS?  I'd be happy if when I checked out a file, the directory it is stored in became writeable(u+w), and when all files in the directory are checked in, the directory becomes readonly again (ugo-w).

As a side note I thought this might be a complexity of my having the files stored on a Linux box.  But I tried it with a local file stored on my Win 7 PC, and got the same result.  TFS will set the read-only file attribute.  But even with read-only attribute set, I can still delete / overwrite / rename a file.  I suppose because I'm an administrator of my PC (the security tab of the file properties shows I have full control).

So I think it's a generic TFS question.  Since TFS uses the read-only attribute to prevent files from being **modified** outside of TFS without being checked out, is there a good way for TFS to prevent them from being deleted / overwritten / renamed outside of TFS?

Without that, I think I'm at risk of my local files accidentally becoming out of synch with the repository, and that doesn't seem like a good thing.

Comment: The hoops I'm trying to jump through above are because I'll be editing files outside of Visual Studio.  But from a little more reading, looks like I'll be better off using a local workspace instead of a server workspace.  Since with a local workspace, TFS doesn't toggle the read only bit on check out / check in.  You can edit a file with whatever you want, and TFS will detect the changes. This sounds closer to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you said **local workspace** is more appropriate for your situation. 
And this is also available with TFS 2012.

A local workspace caches the unmodified version of each of your files to enable you to edit, compare, and do other things without being connected to the server. Just like work offline. Besides when you add or delete files outside of Visual Studio, the program **automatically detects these changes.**

Even though you have permission of the directory in which foo.txt is stored, such as delete foo.txt, you still can't be able to check in TFS  source contol without  sufficient permissions. And if you accidentally delete the file, also easy to restore locally, just get your files again.

Moreover, if you are an administrator, you can [specify which type of workspace Visual Studio creates for](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace#manage-team-project-collection-workspace-settings-for-your-team) your team members by default: Local or Server.

Take a look this excellent blog: [Server workspaces vs. local workspaces](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2013/05/28/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces/) which helps you clearly understand differences between the two.